# Add Marker in GSMapView

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm using Google Maps in my iOS application. It will draw the line between two coordinates and also add start and end position as "Markers" on the map.

[image: Have a look at the image]

I'm using below code to add start and end markers

```
    //myLatLngArrayList is array of coordinates with latitude and longitude positions
    markerA.position =  (curDrill.myLatLngArrayList.first)! as CLLocationCoordinate2D
    markerA.map = mapView
    markerA.icon = UIImage(named: markerImages.0)

    markerB.position =  (curDrill.myLatLngArrayList.last)! as CLLocationCoordinate2D
    markerB.map = mapView
    markerB.icon = UIImage(named: markerImages.1)
```

I'm using below code for drawing line:

```
    let path = GMSMutablePath()
    for coord in curDrill.myLatLngArrayList {
        path.add(coord)
    }

    let drillPath = GMSPolyline.init(path: path)
    drillPath.strokeWidth = 2.0
    drillPath.strokeColor = UIColor(Utility.getDrillColor(type: curDrill.type))
    drillPath.map = mapView
```

The problem is that Marker positions are not matching with line start and end points. Marker A is not touching start of the line and Marker B is not touching end of the line.

I couldn't identify what is missing in my code.

Comment: do you redraw polyline if your markers coordinates are changed ?

Comment: No, its not live map. Co-ordinates are already saved and sent by server. So its just one time drawing of polyline.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding all the steps coordinates which you receives from google API from First point to Last point.

Comment: Problem is not with with drawing poly line. If you noticed the image, only marker positions are not matching.

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with groundAnchor of your marker.

The ground anchor specifies the point in the icon image that is anchored to the marker's position on the Earth's surface. This point is specified within the continuous space [0.0, 1.0] x [0.0, 1.0], where (0,0) is the top-left corner of the image, and (1,1) is the bottom-right corner.

This working for me:

```
marker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
```